# convert a before insert trigger that update the rows from for each ROW, to STATEMENT

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm using postgresql 15.

i have a table called calls with columns `the_time timestamptz`, `a_number text`, `a_prefix text`, `b_number text` and `b_prefix text`.

I get bulk data as csv and i insert it directly to the db.

the data doesn't contain prefixes, i need to fill the columns `a_prefix` and `b_prefix` myself.

i created a trigger for each ROW with the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calls_prefixes()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
      NEW.a_prefix=(select p.prefix from prefixes p
          where NEW.a_number like (p.prefix || '%')
          order by p.prefix_length desc limit 1);
      NEW.b_prefix=(select p.prefix from prefixes p
                        where NEW.b_number like (p.prefix || '%')
                        order by p.prefix_length desc limit 1);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER prefixes
BEFORE INSERT  ON calls
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calls_prefixes();
```

this works fine but a bit slow.. since i insert data in bulk, i wanna see if i can fill the missing prefixes in one update for the news rows and see if it changes performance.

i googled, asked chat gpt... asked on irc.. but somehow i'm still very confused on how to achieve this.

I assume the trigger will get the a hold of all the news and i need to run an update statement on them ? i'm guessing ? i have no clue.

i googled and couldn't find one working example of a before insert, for each STATEMENT, so i'm pretty lost.

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Your title description is backwards, you want to convert a `row` trigger to a `statement` trigger. Your title says *...  for each STATEMENT, to ROW*. 2) `NEW` is not available in a `statement` trigger per [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). 3) Why not just run the queries outside a trigger after the bulk update?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - thanks, fixed the title. sometimes other systems do basic inserts and i want to support that too but in general you're right. anywho i really want to learn how to use statement triggers and then i'll decide which option to go :)

Comment: 1) Read up on transition relations here [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and here [plpgsql transition table example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE) 2) Use a `FOR STATEMENT ` trigger and run the queries you would have run at end of batch operation inside the trigger function.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - ohhh i was on that page and i didn't notice the full example, thanks a lot! going over it

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - ok.. so i'm guessing the old_table is the table before the insert and the new_table is the table after the insert? or new_table is just the new rows? still need to investigate this, but good progress :)

Comment: No read the CREATE TRIGGER link I posted. Fora  transition table or the NEW/OLD records(in FOR EACH ROW trigger) an INSERT only has NEW, UPDATE has NEW and OLD and DELETE only has OLD.

Comment: i'm still confused, can't find a proper way to update the columns of the new data in a statement trigger.

Comment: Update your question with some example data showing what you are starting with and what you want to end up with.

Answer (score 1):

I write sample query for you, for about creating and using triggers for each statement.

```
-- create table
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 text NOT NULL, c2 integer);
CREATE TABLE t2 (c1 text NOT NULL, c2 integer);

-- create trigger function 
CREATE or replace FUNCTION insert_log() 
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $$
DECLARE
    r1 record;
begin
    
    insert into t2
    select * from new_table;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t1_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON t1 REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_log();

-- insert sample data for testing 
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('tp1', 10), ('tp2', 20), ('tp3', 30);

-- select data 
select * from t2 

c1   | c2 |
-----+----+
tup1 | 10 |
tup2 | 20 |
tup3 | 30 |
```

In triggers for each statement we can not use `new` object, because `new` objects is not a record, this object works such as table.

Answer (score 1):

A rough draft. I added a PRIMARY KEY to make it easier to follow.

```
create table calls (
    line_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    the_time timestamptz, 
    a_number text, 
    a_prefix text, 
    b_number text, 
    b_prefix text);

    
create or replace function calls_prefix()
returns trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$

begin 

    update 
        calls 
    set 
        a_prefix = p.prefix
    from 
        new_tbl,
        LATERAL (select 
            prefix 
        from 
            prefixes
        where
            new_tbl.a_number  like(prefix ||'%')
        order by
            prefix_length desc
        limit 1) as p
    where
        calls.line_id = new_tbl.line_id
    and
         new_tbl.a_number like(p.prefix ||'%')
    ;

   
    update 
        calls 
    set 
        b_prefix = p.prefix
    from 
        new_tbl,
        LATERAL (select 
            prefix 
        from 
            prefixes
        where
            new_tbl.b_number  like(prefix ||'%')
        order by
            prefix_length desc 
            limit 1) as p
    where
        calls.line_id = new_tbl.line_id
    and
         new_tbl.b_number like(p.prefix ||'%')
            ;
    
return null;
end;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER prefix_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON calls REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_tbl
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE calls_prefix();
    
create table prefixes(
    prefix text,
    prefix_length integer);
    
insert into prefixes values('ap', 2), ('ap2', 3), ('bp', 2), ('bp2', 3);

insert into 
    calls(the_time, a_number, b_number) 
values  
    (now(), 'ap12', 'bp12'), (now(), 'ap12', 'bp12'),
    (now(), 'ap23', 'bp24'), (now(), 'ap25', 'bp26');

select * from calls;
 line_id |            the_time            | a_number | a_prefix | b_number | b_prefix 
---------+--------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------
       1 | 07/04/2023 11:22:03.038124 PDT | ap12     | ap       | bp12     | bp
       2 | 07/04/2023 11:22:03.038124 PDT | ap12     | ap       | bp12     | bp
       3 | 07/04/2023 11:22:03.038124 PDT | ap23     | ap2      | bp24     | bp2
       4 | 07/04/2023 11:22:03.038124 PDT | ap25     | ap2      | bp26     | bp2
```

Issues with above there is no Primary Key to update against.

Comment: in an after insert trigger, the new rows still weren't added to the new table so i can't update the table. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: The example above shows you are wrong. The insert only included the `the_time, a_number, b_number` fields. The `a_prefix` and `b_prefix` fields  where updated by the trigger function. `AFTER INSERT` means just that, the trigger and it's function run after the insert was done so the rows are there. The same goes for `REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_tbl`, `new_tbl` holds the data just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a large number of prefixes defined, then using `LIKE` will be slow because the search will not be able to use an index. To demonstrate the potential difference in performance, the following setup is run:

```
CREATE TABLE prefixes (
  PREFIX text PRIMARY KEY,
  prefix_length integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (length(prefix)) STORED
);

INSERT INTO prefixes(PREFIX)
SELECT n::text
FROM generate_series(0,9999) s(n);

CREATE TABLE calls (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  a_number text,
  a_prefix text,
  b_number text,
  b_prefix text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calls_prefixes_using_like()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
  UPDATE calls
    SET a_prefix = t.a_prefix,
        b_prefix = t.b_prefix
    FROM (SELECT new_rows.id, a_prefixes.prefix AS a_prefix, b_prefixes.prefix AS b_prefix
            FROM new_rows
            LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT new_rows.id, p.prefix
                                 FROM prefixes p
                                 WHERE new_rows.a_number LIKE p.prefix || '%'
                                 ORDER BY p.prefix_length DESC
                                 LIMIT 1) a_prefixes
              ON new_rows.id = a_prefixes.id
            LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT new_rows.id, p.prefix
                                 FROM prefixes p
                                 WHERE new_rows.b_number LIKE p.prefix || '%'
                                 ORDER BY p.prefix_length DESC
                                 LIMIT 1) b_prefixes
              ON new_rows.id = b_prefixes.id) t
    WHERE calls.id = t.id;
    
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calls_prefixes_using_substring()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
  UPDATE calls
    SET a_prefix = t.a_prefix,
        b_prefix = t.b_prefix
    FROM (SELECT new_rows.id, a_prefixes.prefix AS a_prefix, b_prefixes.prefix AS b_prefix
            FROM new_rows
            LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT DISTINCT ON (new_rows.id) new_rows.id, p.prefix
                                 FROM generate_series(1, length(new_rows.a_number)) s(n)
                                 JOIN prefixes p
                                   ON p.prefix = substring(new_rows.a_number, 1, s.n)
                                 ORDER BY new_rows.id, s.n DESC) a_prefixes
              ON new_rows.id = a_prefixes.id
            LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT DISTINCT ON (new_rows.id) new_rows.id, p.prefix
                                 FROM generate_series(1, length(new_rows.b_number)) s(n)
                                 JOIN prefixes p
                                   ON p.prefix = substring(new_rows.b_number, 1, s.n)
                                 ORDER BY new_rows.id, s.n DESC) b_prefixes
              ON new_rows.id = b_prefixes.id) t
    WHERE calls.id = t.id;
    
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Running the following commands:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER prefixes
AFTER INSERT ON calls
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_rows
FOR STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE calls_prefixes_using_like();

TRUNCATE TABLE calls;

VACUUM FULL calls;

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)
INSERT INTO calls(a_number, b_number)
SELECT (random() * 10000000)::integer::text, (random() * 1000000)::integer::text
  FROM generate_series(1,1000) s(n);
```

produced this output:

```
 Insert on public.calls  (cost=0.00..50.00 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=3.979..3.980 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=3615 read=3 dirtied=13 written=11
   ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=0.00..50.00 rows=1000 width=132) (actual time=0.099..1.186 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Output: nextval('calls_id_seq'::regclass), "*SELECT*".text, NULL::text, "*SELECT*".text_1, NULL::text
         Buffers: shared hit=1000 dirtied=1
         ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.generate_series s  (cost=0.00..35.00 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=0.089..0.454 rows=1000 loops=1)
               Output: (((random() * '10000000'::double precision))::integer)::text, (((random() * '1000000'::double precision))::integer)::text
               Function Call: generate_series(1, 1000)
 Planning Time: 0.053 ms
 Trigger prefixes: time=2350.041 calls=1
 Execution Time: 2354.059 ms
(11 rows)
```

The following replaces the trigger function with an implementation that uses substrings and repeats the experiment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER prefixes
AFTER INSERT ON calls
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_rows
FOR STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE calls_prefixes_using_substring();

TRUNCATE TABLE calls;

VACUUM FULL calls;

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)
INSERT INTO calls(a_number, b_number)
SELECT (random() * 10000000)::integer::text, (random() * 1000000)::integer::text
  FROM generate_series(1,1000) s(n);
```

This run produced the following results:

```
 Insert on public.calls  (cost=0.00..50.00 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=4.426..4.427 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=3615 read=3 dirtied=12 written=11
   ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=0.00..50.00 rows=1000 width=132) (actual time=0.153..1.309 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Output: nextval('calls_id_seq'::regclass), "*SELECT*".text, NULL::text, "*SELECT*".text_1, NULL::text
         Buffers: shared hit=1000
         ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.generate_series s  (cost=0.00..35.00 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=0.142..0.507 rows=1000 loops=1)
               Output: (((random() * '10000000'::double precision))::integer)::text, (((random() * '1000000'::double precision))::integer)::text
               Function Call: generate_series(1, 1000)
 Planning Time: 0.067 ms
 Trigger prefixes: time=24.622 calls=1
 Execution Time: 29.092 ms
(11 rows)
```

For these two runs, the implementation of the trigger function that took advantage of the index on `prefixes` ran about 95 times faster than the one using `LIKE`. Repeated runs produced comparable results. The relative performance of the two approaches is highly dependent on the number of rows in `prefixes` and the number of rows being inserted into `calls`.